# Correct way to query from BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

```
  String query = "SELECT * FROM "+"`"+tableId.getProject()+"."+tableId.getDataset()+"."+tableName+"`";

1 - first 
        QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query).build();
        try 
        {
            TableResult result = bigquery.query(queryConfig);

            for (FieldValueList row : result.iterateAll()) 
            {
             .............
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Or like this

2 - second

```
        QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query)
                .setUseLegacySql(false)
                .build();

        JobId jobId = JobId.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        Job queryJob = bigquery.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(queryConfig).setJobId(jobId).build());
queryJob = queryJob.waitFor();
 TableResult result = null;
       try 
        {
            result = queryJob.getQueryResults();
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

Trying to query values from table for this found two different approaches in this which will be effective?
what is the actual difference between these?
which one will do query efficiently? performance wise